# How to loop through list, find data and send in HTML email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook.application

I have the following list with one, or multiple entries for a specific ID.
[image]

I have a second list with with unique IDs and email addresses.
[image]

I need to loop through the list, send an email to every ID and list data from each matching row in the email, also mentioning the total amount.

Example of the email sent to ID 1234 foo@bar.com:
[image]

What I have so far:

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
    
    Dim strbody1 As String
    Dim strbody2 As String
    Dim Signature As String
    
    Dim i As Integer, Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant, lr As Long
    
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    strbody1 = "Hi,<br><br>" & _
                "Test.<br><br>"
    strbody2 = "Test1.<br><br>" & _
                "Foobar,"
                
    Signature = "<H4><B>My Name</B></H4>" & _
                  "Something<br>" & _
                  "Something<br>" & _
                  "T: +1 000 000 000<br>" & _
                  "<A href=""mailto:foo@bar.com"">foo@bar.com</A><br>" & _
                  "<A HREF=""http://www.bar.com"">www.bar.com</A>"
    
    If MsgBox(("This will send all emails in the list. Do you want to proceed?"), vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    For i = 2 To lr
        With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
            .Subject = Range("B" & i).Value
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "foo@bar.com"
            .To = Range("A" & i).Value
            .Body = Range("C" & i).Value
            .HTMLBody = strbody1 & strbody2 & Signature
            .Send 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
        End With
    Next i
    MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Mail_Object = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use pivots or filtered lists and pop them in emails. I'd probably loop through the 2nd list and collect the details for each item directly into the table in the html email. Anyhow, what exactly is your question? Try building a code and if you get stuck somewhere, we can help.

Comment: I'm not sure how to start. Take the list into an array, or do it another way...

Comment: Maybe start with creating two `for` loops, then using `vba filter() function` to filter an array of string items, potentially your Ids.  Reference : https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/filter-arrays-function.   As is noted by @vacip, build code, then someone may assist further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the IDs into a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-objectDictionary). Then scan the data for each ID in turn adding the rows with that ID to an html table. If performance is an issue copy the data to an array first and scan that.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SendEMail()

    Const WS_ID = "Sheet1"
    Const WS_DATA = "Sheet2"
    Const HEAD = "<head><style>body {font: 20px Verdana;} " & _
                 " .amount {text-align:right;}</style></head>"
    Const TABLE = "<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""5""" & _
              " border=""1"">" & _
              "<tr bgcolor=""#EEEEEE""><th>REF</th><th>Amount</th></tr>"
    Const TXT = "This is a test email"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim dictID As Object, ID, addr As String

    Set dictID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 
    ' get list of IDS
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_ID)
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        ID = Trim(ws.Cells(i, "A"))
        addr = Trim(ws.Cells(i, "B"))
        If dictID.exists(ID) Then
            MsgBox ID & " is duplicated", vbCritical, "Duplicate ID"
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf InStr(1, addr, "@") > 0 Then
            dictID.Add ID, addr
        End If
    Next

    Dim objOut
    Set objOut = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' scan data
    Dim total As Double, htm As String
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_DATA)
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each ID In dictID
        total = 0
        addr = dictID(ID)
        ' build html table
        htm = "<html>" & HEAD & "<body><p>" & TXT & "</p>" & TABLE
        For i = 2 To iLastRow
            If ws.Cells(i, "A") = CStr(ID) Then
               htm = htm & "<tr><td>" & ws.Cells(i, "B") & _
                     "</td><td class=""amount"">" & ws.Cells(i, "C") & "</td></tr>" & vbCrLf
               total = total + ws.Cells(i, "C")
            End If
        Next
        total = Format(total, "#,##0")
        htm = htm & "<tr bgcolor=""#CCFFCC"" style=""font-weight:bold""><td>TOTAL</td>" & _
              "<td class=""amount"">" & total & "</td></tr></table><br/>" & _
              "<p>The total amount is " & total & "</p></body></html>"
         
        ' send email
        Call SendOneEMail(objOut, CStr(ID), addr, htm)
        
    Next
    MsgBox dictID.Count & " emails sent", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub SendOneEMail(objOut, sID As String, sTo As String, htm As String)
    
    ' create email
    With objOut.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
        .Subject = sID
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "foo@bar.com"
        .To = sTo
        .HTMLBody = htm
        .Display
        '.Send 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That does exactly what I need!

Comment: I realized that the Dictionary object can only have one value (in this case: ID= addr). How can I modify the above code to add another value to each ID (a name to be used in the email). I tried adapting your code using a Class Module, but I could not get it going.

Comment: @MikeSkril Is the name in column C, to the right of the email address ?

Comment: Yes Sir, it is in the C column.

Comment: @MikeSkril Store the email and name with `dictID.Add ID, Array(addr, name)` and then use `addr = dictID(ID)(0) :  name = dictID(ID)(1)` to retrieve them.

Comment: Great, that's an elegant solution! If modified as per your instructions. I defined the name like so: CoName = dictID(ID)(1). How do I get 'CoName' over into the mail Sub when I call it: Call SendOneEMail(objOut, CStr(ID), addr, htm)

Comment: @MikeSkril simplest way is add another parameter `Call SendOneEMail(objOut, CStr(ID), addr, name, htm)` and modify sub line `Sub SendOneEMail(objOut, sID As String, sTo As String, sName as String, htm As String)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253666/discussion-between-mikeskril-and-cdp1802).